# Events in JS

Tags: javascript

почему событие не оставляет изменения, а применяет лишь на мгновение(при нажатии кнопки)

```
(function(){
    var addWant = document.getElementById("add"),
        newDiv = document.createElement("div"),
        content = document.createTextNode("will here want."),
        includeDivHere = document.getElementById("createWant");
        addWant.onclick = function(){
            newDiv.className = "wantClass";
            newDiv.appendChild(content);
            includeDivHere.parentNode.appendChild(newDiv);
            console.log(newDiv);
        };
})();
```

Comment: Вообще, что такое value в данном контексте, по-Вашему?  
И что есть "эффект"? Текст, который в элемент с id="n" вставляется? Или создание новых div? Конкретнее.

Comment: 'wantClass' применяется и пропадает сразу
тоже самое и с   document.getElementById('n').value = 'is work it';

Comment: Может, у вас ещё есть слушатель click, кроме этого?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('n').innerText = 'is work it';
```

Так текст в элемент с id="n" вставится.

Comment: При таком варианте текст и на полсекунды не рисуется.

Comment: Я так не думаю http://jsfiddle.net/bmsdfxwp/

Comment: странно,но у меня все браузеры отказываются нормально себя вести при таком коде...

Comment: У меня только Огнелис не захотел добавлять текст в div, остальные ок (даже ослик).

Comment: innerText не везде поддерживается, используйте innerHTML

Comment: перегрузился с Linux,ситуация та же... Не пойму как у вас работает,а у меня нет
к тому же присвоение не принципиально,главная задача в div
а он тоже пропадает

Comment: У меня с фиддла код работает.
@Zein вы хоть загляните в консоль, может там ошибки есть (хотя, сомневаюсь)

Comment: хоть?)
я все "куски" стараюсь там тестить,прежде чем кодить дальше

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent